# Entity Framework doesn't associate a still existing object in the database context with the same object referenced from a different class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a `message` to my database
Message.cs:

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SenderId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }

    public MessageTrigger Trigger { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedTs { get; set; }
}
```

I have also a table named `Recipients`
Recipient.cs:

```
public class Recipient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeliviredOn { get; set; }
}
```

As you see both tables have their foreign key set to the Id of an User
User.cs:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now while adding a new Message to the database

```
 public void Add(Message message)
 {          
     using (var ctx = new ShowcaseContext())
     {
         foreach (var reci in message.Recipients)
         {
             ctx.Users.Attach(reci.User);
         }

         ctx.Messages.Add(message);
         ctx.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

I have to attach all the user to the context, because if not EF is adding the User again to the database.
This worked all fine while `Message` doesn't had a `Sender`. Now after adding the `Sender and SenderId` properties
to the `Message` class, EF adds the `user` again to the user table. So I tried something like that:

```
 public void Add(Message message)
 {          
     using (var ctx = new ShowcaseContext())
     {
         foreach (var reci in message.Recipients)
         {
             ctx.Users.Attach(reci.User);
         }

         ctx.Users.Attach(message.Sender);  // Here the error is thrown
         ctx.Messages.Add(message);
         ctx.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

But then this Error occures:

> Error attaching an entity of type Entities.User,
>   because another entity of the same type already has an identical primary key value

So the user of `sender` is already in the database context, but the context doesn't seem to associate this user with the user of the `sender`.
And because of that the userobject of `sender` is added to the database as an duplicate.

Is there someone out there who knows a solution for this problem?
I just want to add a `message` to the database without EF adding an already existing user again to the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with this:

```
public void Add(Message message)
{          
    using (var ctx = new ShowcaseContext())
    {
        foreach (var reci in message.Recipients)
        {
            ctx.Users.Attach(reci.User);
        }

        ctx.Messages.Add(message);
        ctx.Entry(message.Sender).State = EntityState.Detached;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

After adding the message to the context, I explicitly detach the `sender` user object from the context.
I guess it is not the best solution, but the only one I can think of which works.